# When to use spherical and when to use cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do we know when to use spherical coordinates and when to use cylindrical coordinates? **What do we base it on, the surface or the equation of the function we are given?**

e.g in a question I'm given $z^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}+1,z>0$ and $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=3$. I thought we should use spherical coordinates but we have to use cylindrical so clearly there should be a way to determine when to use which.

Comment: There is something strange here. If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3$, then  $z^2 = 3 - x^2 - y^2$.  If you are also given that $z^2 = 1 + x^2 + y^2$, then $3 - x^2 - y^2 = 1 + x^2 + y^2$, which means that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. These facts and the fact $z > 0$ imply that $z = 2$.  Where's the surface?